# Insert text in 2000 cells of HTML table

Tags: html

I have been trying this for many days. I'm trying to add text to an HTML table of about 2000 cells! You can see why you'd definitely need to use a macro here.

So, the macro is built with generic commands, and I'm using a program called Macro Toolworks. This works perfectly in some HTML tables, but the extra problem I have here is that to move from one cell to the next after adding one line of text, you need to click Alt and then left mouse click to get into your new cell below, and then add the next line of text there, and so on. Because you can't move to the next cell using only the keyboard unfortunately.:-)))))) No shortcuts. So, you need to duplicate what the mouse would do at some point.

So, you need to click the mouse slightly below your last position, like about 10 or 20 pixels below.

The crazy thing is that I have tried different things and got unexpected results, like random browser tabs opening in Chrome, random files and folders opening. Really strange!

So, this is what I'm trying now, and it opens random tabs and folders instead of goint to the next cell below:

```
LINE OF TEXT 1.<alt><alt>
<wx>(1000)
<mousemove_relative_pos>
<mm>(0,30)
<wx>(2000)
<mlbd>
<mlbu>
<wx>(1000)
LINE OF TEXT 2.
```

If someone could help it would mean sooo much! Maybe just a small contribution would make a difference. As this is using generic commands, it's not really a programming language.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why should you use a macro...and not regular html/javascript?
Also, if you are adding text to the 2000 cells, why dont you generate the table with text already in place. What exactly is the function of this table.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! I have just basic knowledge of HTML and javascript. It's an HTML table for subtitles, and I can only access it online, the way it is. I can't modify it directly offline. Otherwise it would be totally simple. The macro works perfectly in similar cases where you can move from one cell to the next using the keyboard, like with Enter or Tab or any other key. The problem here is that you can only move to the next cell with the mouse, clicking on the next cell below.

Comment: If you cant modify it directly, then you cant save it directly either. I think you could just download that html table and edit it offline.( even in Excel or OpenOffice ).
Then you can use arrow keys/tabs etc, and save it as your own file.( i assume you cant save it in the server where you scrape the data from, so you need to copy it anyways )

Comment: Unfortunately I can't download it to modify it offline and I can't upload a new table. I can only modify it online as it is. I access it via user and password.That's why I was trying my best to modify my current macro to adapt it for this situation. But do you think this could be solved using javascript or jQuery or something else?

Comment: If its a webpage, then you can download it. All web pages can be downloaded( if you are viewing a page, then you have actually already downloaded it ).
You can download facebook, or stack overflow etc. Just right click and "save page as". Same option should be available under browser file tab...somewhere.
Once you have downloaded it, the page can be edited( table can be opened in excel too )

Comment: OK.... I downloaded it, saved it to the desktop. Now... How do I edit it??? No idea. But even more important... How would I upload it later, once I had the info loaded into it?????

Comment: You edit it like you edit any other html code...pick your favorite text editor and start typing.
And you upload it ... the way you upload any other file of the web page. How would you "upload" your changes if you used a macro ?

Comment: Well, I definitely can't upload it like a file to the web page. I only have access to that page via my user and password and that only allows me to update that exact html table line by line.To answer your second question, the macro would mimic myself typing each line. That's what  I want to avoid doing directly and that's why I thought about the macro. I used this macro before to add line after line to a table, but on a different site where I could move to the next cell of the table using the keyboard. Here I can only move using the mouse first.

Comment: @AlinaR, could you please clarify: is that table some kind of interactive web interface like Google Spreadsheets? How does it save the changes you make there (automatically after you move the focus away from the cell or you need to click the "Save" button)?

Comment: Hi Ilya and Rainer! Thanks so much for helping! Yes, it is a bit similar to Google Sheets, more like Amara subtitles, but not exactly the same. Yes, it saves automatically every line after you move to the next cell or when you change to another tab in Google Chrome.

Comment: Amazing solution below, Rainer, but I don't have any programming knowledge. I know how to open the developer tools via "inspect element/see page code", but I don't know how to change things inside that. Also, I'm not supposed to be doing that!!! Even worse, what if I mess things up? It would be horrible. :-(

Comment: A sample of my macro, but it's not working fine:<wx>(1953,0)LINE OF TEXT 1.<wx>(1844,0)<#>
<mm>(875,556)<#>
<mlbd><#>
<wx>(109,0)<#>
<mlbu><#>
<wx>(1297,0)LINE OF TEXT 2.<wx>(406,0)<#>
<mm>(875,556)<#>
<mlbd><#>
<wx>(125,0)<#>
<mlbu><#>
<wx>(1125,0)LINE OF TEXT 3.<wx>(454,0)<#>
<mlbd><#>
<wx>(109,0)<#>
<mlbu><#>
<wx>(2562,0)LINE OF TEXT 4.<wx>(281,0)<#>

Comment: @AlinaR You dont have to worry about messing things up. None of the changes you make to the structure/looks of the pages effect the actual page. Editing stuff using developer tools only affects a local copy of the website that's in your computer. 
If the site is similar to google sheets, then it might not even be an HTML table.( google sheets is html canvas - completely different stuff from html tables )

Comment: OK, wait a minute. But if the changes are not done to the actual page like you say, then it's like  I'm not changing anything. If I load all my info the way you suggest, nobody else is going to see it. Right? And they have to see it. So... Not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
setContent = () => {
  // below are 2 table rows filled with text, you could 
  // have as many as you want
  const content = [
    'first cell content', 'second', 'third', 'fourth',
    'and', 'so', 'on', '!'
  ];

  const tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('table#demo tr td');
  tableCells.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.innerText = content.shift();
  });
};
```

```css
#demo {
  border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 #demo th {
  border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
  padding:5px;
  background:#F0F0F0;
 }
 #demo td {
  border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<table id="demo" contenteditable="true">
 <caption>Then use arrow keys(up/down) to navigate cells</caption>
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Header 1</th>
  <th>Header 2</th>
  <th>Header 3</th>
  <th>Header 4</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="setContent()" style="font-size: 1em; margin-top: 1em;">set content</button>
```

Ids hard to say what is the best way to solve your problem, without actually seeing the webpage...since they behave differently. Below is one way of making a table content editable. Use your browser developer tools to add contenteditable="true" to the table. Then you can use arrow keys to move around the cells. Another option is to use javascript and fill in all your data in a form of comma separated text and assign it to the table all at once.

The developer tools will give you a lot of control over the table and its content.